# Simplifying logarithm of a product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, products

My textbook reads (without explanation, naturally):

$\log \prod_{y=0}^{9}{(1+\frac{1}{10x+y})} = \log{(1+\frac{1}{x})}$

Wondering how this was achieved...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $1+\frac{1}{10x+y}=\frac{10x+y+1}{10x+y}$, so the product is: $$\prod_{y=0}^{9}{\left(1+\frac{1}{10x+y}\right)}=\frac{10x+1}{10x}\cdot\frac{10x+2}{10x+1}\cdot\frac{10x+3}{10x+2}\dots\frac{10x+10}{10x+9}.$$  Everything cancels out except the first denominator and the last numerator, giving $$\frac{10x+10}{10x}=\frac{x+1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: Ah okay so sort of like a telescoping product

Comment: Right, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\prod_{y=1}^9\left(1+\frac{1}{10x+y}\right)=\left(\frac{10x+1}{10x}\right)\left(\frac{10x+2}{10x+1}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{10x+9}{10x+8}\right)\left(\frac{10x+10}{10x+9}\right)=1+\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
For an 'automatic derivation', you can use the *Pochhammer Symbol*
$\ds{\pars{a} _{n}}$ and its relation to the *Gamma Function* $\ds{\Gamma}$. Namely, $\ds{\pars{a}_{n} = \Gamma\pars{a + n}/\Gamma\pars{a}}$:
\begin{align}
\prod_{y = 0}^{9}\pars{1 + {1 \over 10x + y}} & =
{\prod_{y = 0}^{9}\pars{y + 10x + 1} \over
\prod_{y = 0}^{9}\pars{y + 10x}} = {\pars{10x + 1}_{\ 10} \over \pars{10x}_{\ 10}} =
{\Gamma\pars{10x + 11} \over \Gamma\pars{10x + 1}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{10x} \over \Gamma\pars{10x + 10}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{10x + 11} \over \Gamma\pars{10x + 10}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{10x} \over \Gamma\pars{10x + 1}} = \pars{10x + 10}{1 \over 10x} =
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px solid navy]{\ds{1 + {1 \over x}}}
\end{align}